# verify a signature using the RSA public key

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

To verify a signature using the RSA public key, I used the following code based on the OpenSSL library:

```
bool verify(unsigned char md[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH], std::string public_key, std::string signature) {
    // Parse the public key data into an RSA structure
    const auto* p = (const unsigned char*)public_key.c_str();
    RSA* rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(nullptr, &p, (long)public_key.size());
    if (!rsa) {
        return false;
    }

    int result = RSA_verify(NID_sha256, md, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH, (const unsigned char *)signature.c_str(), signature.size(), rsa);
    RSA_free(rsa);

    return result == 1;
}
```

since "d2i_RSA_PUBKEY", "RSA_verify", and "RSA_free" are deprecated in openssl3, i tried to update the code using EVP_PKEY as follow:

```
bool verify(unsigned char md[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH], std::string public_key, std::string signature) {
    const auto* p = (const unsigned char*)public_key.c_str();
    EVP_PKEY* evp_key = d2i_PUBKEY(nullptr, &p, (long)public_key.size());
    if (!evp_key) {
        return false;
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    if (!ctx) {
        EVP_PKEY_free(evp_key);
        return false;
    }
    if (EVP_DigestVerifyInit(ctx, nullptr, EVP_sha256(), nullptr, evp_key) != 1) {
        EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);
        EVP_PKEY_free(evp_key);
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(ctx, md, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH) != 1) {
        EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);
        EVP_PKEY_free(evp_key);
        return false;
    }

    int result = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, (const unsigned char*)signature.c_str(), signature.size());

    EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(evp_key);

    return result == 1;
}
```

To check the correctness of the function, I used the following values for testing:

```
std::string rsa_signature("\x8b\x2b\x21\x37\xcb\x1e\x99\x3a\x5f\x61\x1c\x47\x4c\xd2\xf0\x92\xeb\xe1\x3e\x9c\xb9\x93\x00\x2d\xd2\x94\x57\xb8\x68\x03\xec\xf9\x01\x41\x1c\x1a\x71\x23\x0e\x11\xd0\x1c\x30\x92\xdc\xb6\xb3\xe4\xcd\x39\x70\x45\x20\x05\x52\xf5\xbb\x35\xef\xf8\x37\x73\x67\x6e\xeb\x4b\x65\x9f\x87\x37\xc5\x28\x8c\x53\xa5\xa4\x30\x74\xb3\x5c\xad\x17\x52\x7a\x00\xb0\x5e\x14\xfb\xb6\x82\x39\xb8\xad\xef\x62\xd2\xeb\x0d\xfc\xe5\x45\x96\x98\xa9\x44\xf2\x36\x44\x8e\xd3\x78\xf3\x9f\x52\x09\x53\xa4\x39\xaa\x7c\x77\xab\x61\x4f\xb4\x40\xa7\xa3\xbf\xd3\xa4\xba\x22\x3c\xc4\xc2\x77\xa2\x52\x83\x1a\x27\x9b\x02\xe5\x01\xd3\x60\x2d\x5f\x8d\xc2\x22\x42\xf9\x87\x13\x44\x36\x54\x03\x51\x29\x55\x5a\xbf\x38\x81\x0e\x0a\x39\xce\x8b\xd7\x60\x1b\x37\x33\x77\x2a\x91\x51\x09\x83\xca\x70\x46\x62\xe2\x4f\x3f\xd3\x1c\x7b\x30\xe9\xdd\x5e\x72\xf7\x3c\xb3\x21\xf6\xfa\x6e\x59\xce\xaa\xf1\x29\x7f\x1c\xa6\x21\x3d\xd2\x79\x54\xe6\x19\xe3\x1b\x17\x53\x1c\x69\xbb\x8a\x29\x10\x80\x11\x24\xda\x03\x7f\x6d\x32\xbd\x91\x0d\xad\x16\x70\xcb\xba\x3e\x1c\x11\xca\xc0\x7c\x44\x4d", 256);

std::string rsa_pubkey("\x30\x82\x01\x22\x30\x0d\x06\x09\x2a\x86\x48\x86\xf7\x0d\x01\x01\x01\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x0f\x00\x30\x82\x01\x0a\x02\x82\x01\x01\x00\x8f\xfb\xbf\x5c\x37\x63\x94\x3c\xb0\xee\x01\xc4\xb5\xa6\x9a\xb1\x9f\x46\x74\x6f\x16\x38\xa0\x32\x27\x35\xdd\xf0\x71\x6b\x0e\xdc\xf6\x25\xcb\xb2\xed\xea\xfb\x32\xd5\xaf\x1e\x03\x43\x03\x46\xf0\xa7\x39\xdb\x23\x96\x1d\x65\xe5\x78\x51\xf0\x84\xb0\x0e\x12\xac\x0e\x5b\xdc\xc9\xd6\x4c\x7c\x00\xd5\xb8\x1b\x88\x33\x3e\x2f\xda\xeb\xaa\xf7\x1a\x75\xc2\xae\x3a\x54\xde\x37\x8f\x10\xd2\x28\xe6\x84\x79\x4d\x15\xb4\xf3\xbd\x3f\x56\xd3\x3c\x3f\x18\xab\xfc\x2e\x05\xc0\x1e\x08\x31\xb6\x61\xd0\xfd\x9f\x4f\x3f\x64\x0d\x17\x93\xbc\xad\x41\xc7\x48\xbe\x00\x27\xa8\x4d\x70\x42\x92\x05\x54\xa6\x6d\xb8\xde\x56\x6e\x20\x49\x70\xee\x10\x3e\x6b\xd2\x7c\x31\xbd\x1b\x6e\xa4\x3c\x46\x62\x9f\x08\x66\x93\xf9\x2a\x51\x31\xa8\xdb\xb5\x9d\xb9\x0f\x73\xe8\xa0\x09\x32\x01\xe9\x7b\x2a\x8a\x36\xa0\xcf\x17\xb0\x50\x70\x9d\xa2\xf9\xa4\x6f\x62\x4d\xb6\xc9\x31\xfc\xf3\x08\x12\xff\x93\xbd\x62\x31\xd8\x1c\xea\x1a\x9e\xf5\x81\x28\x7f\x75\x5e\xd2\x27\x7a\xc2\x96\xf5\x9d\xdb\x18\xfc\x76\xdc\x46\xf0\x57\xc0\x58\x34\xc8\x22\x2d\x2a\x65\x75\xa7\xd9\x08\x62\xcd\x02\x03\x01\x00\x01", 294);

std::string md = "\x29\x55\xb0\xa4\x40\x7f\xcd\x40\x8e\x7d\xbc\xd9\x46\x21\xa7\x4d\x7f\x61\xb1\xdc\x0a\xe5\x9f\x7c\x52\x29\x73\xb4\x33\x79\x3a\x4c";
std::string bad_md = "\x28\x55\xb0\xa4\x40\x7f\xcd\x40\x8e\x7d\xbc\xd9\x46\x21\xa7\x4d\x7f\x61\xb1\xdc\x0a\xe5\x9f\x7c\x52\x29\x73\xb4\x33\x79\x3a\x4c";
```

and test as follow:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(verify(md_byteArray, rsa_pubkey, rsa_signature));
EXPECT_FALSE(verify(bad_md_byteArray, rsa_pubkey, rsa_signature));
```

The tests pass with the first implementation, but the second implementation always returns false due to result=0.

To verify the correctness of my first implementation and the test values, I ran this Python code with the corresponding parameter values:

```
pub_key = serialization.load_der_public_key(public_key)
pub_key.verify(signature, md, padding.PKCS1v15(), utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA256()))
This code acts as my first implementation.
```

Please help me correct my second implementation that uses OpenSSL 3.

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but `std::string` is defined as `std::basic_string<char>`, whereas for arbitrary byte sequences such as those encountered in cryptography I think you should be using `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`. I don't know if it makes any difference to be honest.

Comment: `EVP_DigestXXX()` hashes the data before signing/verifying, unlike the deprecated `RSA_sign()/verify()` which requires a hash and signs it. The EVP counterpart is `EVP_PKEY_sign()/verify()`. See the documentation for [`EVP_PKEY_verify()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_verify.html) for an example of how to use it. The key import with `d2i_PUBKEY()` can be kept unchanged.

Comment: thank you Topaco, you solve my problem